# How to detect characters and words between these characters in a textbox with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm starting in javascript and I have a problem.
Let's say I have the following text with the characters `@`, `.` and `:` in a textbox, for example:

@green.car-blue:computer

In javascript I would like to recognize those characters and print in console the words that are after each character and before the other character, for example:

```
green is after @ , car-blue is after . , computer is after :
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Regexp.Exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to find all matching occurrences of a string of characters between two of your split characters:

```js
const inp = document.getElementById('input');
let txt = inp.value;

const regex = /([@.:])([^@.:]+)(?=[@.:]|$)/g;

while ((m = regex.exec(txt)) !== null) {
  console.log(`${m[2]} is after ${m[1]}`);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input">@green.car-blue:computer</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps. split method supports regular expressions.

```js
var str = '@green.car-blue:computer';
var signs = str.split(/[^@.:]+/g);
var words = str.split(/[@.:]+/g);

console.log(signs);
console.log(words);
```